# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices Augmented reality

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
while True:

# Stage 1: Read an image from our webcam
image = webcam.get_current_frame()

# Stage 2: Detect edges in image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)

# Stage 3: Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]

for contour in contours:

    # Stage 4: Shape check
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01*perimeter, True)

    if len(approx) == QUADRILATERAL_POINTS:

        # Stage 5: Perspective warping
        topdown_quad = get_topdown_quad(gray, approx.reshape(4, 2))

        # Stage 6: Border check
        if topdown_quad[(topdown_quad.shape[0]/100.0)*5, 
                        (topdown_quad.shape[1]/100.0)*5] > BLACK_THRESHOLD: continue
```

On the line

```
if topdown_quad [(topdown_quad.shape [0] /100.0) * 5, (topdown_quad.shape [1] /100.0) * 5]> BLACK_THRESHOLD: 
    continue
```

is where the error happens

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

`(topdown_quad.shape [0] /100.0) * 5` and `(topdown_quad.shape [1] /100.0) * 5` are float values.

You can't use float values as indices in Python.

That's what the error message (verbose as it may be) is telling you: NumPy extends Python indexing to handle a whole range of different kinds of indices, but they're all still either integers, slices of integers, or special values.

And it's not clear what you actually *want* here. If, say, `topdown_quad.shape[0]` is 75, so `topdown_quad.shape[0] / 100 * 5` is 3.75, do you want row 3, or row 4? You might want to truncate toward 0 (or toward negative infinity, if the values could be negative), or round to nearest, or round IEEE-style with .5 being rounded up or down depending on whether the integral part is even, or anything else.

Whatever you want, you have to write that explicitly. For example, if you want to truncate:

```
    if topdown_quad[int((topdown_quad.shape[0]/100.0)*5),
```